# Bash not running a specific command

Tags: bash, azure, git-bash

I have a command which I want to use for deploying my web app to azure. The line is something like this:

```
 --plan newschoolplan --name newschool-project --runtime 'PYTHON|3.7'
```

But when I run this command, bash shows

```
'3.7' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

its recognizing the 3.7 as a command. How to prevent this?

**EDIT**
Here is the way that is given inside a tutorial.
[image]

Here is a screnshot in the suggested way by an answer. This is not accepted by the cli
[image]

The bash terminal is inside vscode

Comment: can you post a screen shot? its working fine for me

Comment: That looks like an error message from Windows CMD, not bash. Can you clarify *exactly* how you're using this?

Comment: Thanks for the quick support guys. Please check the edit!